# PostgeSQL Trigger St_Intersect Insert, Update

Tags: postgis, postgresql, update, trigger

I have a problem creating a trigger in PostgreSQL that will get data from polygon layer.

Issue:

I have two tables:
1. point (id, geom, address)
2. polygon (id, geom, address)

Polygon table represent House. I would like to, when I create point on polygon that *`point.address`* get data from *`polygon.address`*

I try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $$
  BEGIN
  UPDATE point
  SET address = topology.polygon.address
           from polygon
           where ST_Intersects(polygon.geom, point.geom);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
 AFTER INSERT
 ON topology.point
 FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE  test()
```

[image]

Comment: add `RETURN;` at the end of your function!

Comment: [Postgresql insert trigger to set value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16102188/11654)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment wasn't very thoughtful, albeit true; your function misses a `RETURN;` (which is precisely what that error states).

However, let's think this through:

- you are setting up a trigger working `ON EACH ROW`, that executes a function `AFTER` each new row is inserted; so far no issue, **but** an `AFTER` trigger is significantly more expensive than a `BEFORE` trigger, so avoid it if possible
- in your function, you are issuing an `UPDATE` on *a* table (that happens to be the one you are inserting into); **but** you are updating **the whole table `ON EACH ROW`**! Needless to say, this is bogus.

A `BEFORE` trigger function has access to a special variable; the `NEW` record, holding all values that are being inserted. You can alter these values in the trigger function before they are inserted!

With all this in mind, try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() 
  RETURNS trigger AS
    $$
    BEGIN
      NEW.adress := (
        SELECT ply.address
        FROM topology.polygon AS ply
        WHERE ST_Intersects(ply.geom, NEW.geom)
      );
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
;

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON topology.point
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test()
;
```

Note that you have to `RETURN NEW;`, to give the `INSERT` a record to insert.

Comment: I try as you said, but neither that way problem is'n solwed. Here is the error:
Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
  
  Provider errors:
      PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  column ply.adress does not exist
    LINE 2:         SELECT ply.adress
                           ^
    HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "ply.address".
    QUERY:  SELECT (
            SELECT ply.adress
            FROM topology.polygon AS ply
            WHERE ST_Intersects(ply.geom, NEW.geom)
          )
    CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test() line 3 at assignment

Comment: @DarkoNedic okay, sorry, that's a plain language error; please **read** those error messages at some point; it's even *suggesting* the right column! That's the name of your column, so name it appropriately; `ply.adress` -> `ply.address`

Comment: That was just obvious :) Thank you! It works now!

Comment: @DarkoNedic glad it works! Please mark the answer as correct (hit that little greyed out tick next to the answer) instead of duplicating the answer with your own. I corrected `adress` to `address` in the function.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code that works:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() 
  RETURNS trigger AS
    $$
    BEGIN
      NEW.address := (
        SELECT ply.address
        FROM topology.polygon AS ply
        WHERE ST_Intersects(ply.geom, NEW.geom)
      );
      RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
;


CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON topology.point
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test()
```

And the point got the address from polygon...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found something very usefull, this get address on INSERT and change address when geometry is changed For example change geometry of point on different polygon

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_address () RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
raise notice 'point trigger starts now: %', now();
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN 
    IF
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM
            (SELECT t.id
            FROM point as t,
                polygon as s
            WHERE st_Within(NEW.geom, s.geom)) AS foo) > 0
    THEN
        SELECT polygon.address
    INTO NEW.address
    FROM polygon
    WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, polygon.geom);
    raise notice 'point trigger ends now: %', now();
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
            RAISE notice 'no intersection';
            RAISE notice 'point trigger ends now: %', now();
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
THEN
IF
(ST_Equals (NEW.geom, OLD.geom)=FALSE)
THEN
    IF
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM 
            (SELECT t.id 
             FROM point as t,
                polygon as s
        WHERE st_Within (NEW.geom, s.geom)
            AND (t.id <> OLD.id)) AS foo) > 0
    THEN
SELECT polygon.address
INTO NEW.address
FROM polygon
WHERE ST_Intersects(NEW.geom, polygon.geom);
    RAISE notice 'Interesction fund';
    RETURN NEW;

    ELSE
    SELECT NULL
        INTO new.address;
  RETURN NEW; 
  raise notice 'point trigger ends now: %', now();
  END IF; 
ELSE
Raise Notice 'Update of attribute data';
raise notice 'point trigger ends now: %', now();
Return NEW;
END IF;
END IF; 
END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_point_address
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON point
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_address ()
```

Thanks to @neogis https://gist.github.com/neogis-de/a1d08c38d8b9c5d316c7

Comment: Simpy adding `OR UPDATE` to the trigger, using the function I wrote in my answer, will have the same effect. Only exception: you cannot add the filter to check for differences of `OLD.geom` vs. `NEW.geom`, so every `UPDATE` will execute the intersection check, if `geom` changed or not.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works. Thanks a lot!